# How do I know if I am viewing low resolution or full resolution photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, resolution

On my iPhone 15 Pro Max I have gone to Settings > Photos and then checked option 'Optimise iPhone Storage', so that my photos are stored in iCloud.

When I am viewing a photo in the Photos app, how do I know if I am viewing the viewing the low resolution or full resolution version? How do I download the full resolution version>

Comment: It does not appear there's a trivial indicator. Most of the time, you'll see a clear switchover. One way you can force it is clicking the "Edit" button. The editing UI won't come up until it's finished downloading the full image. Note that sometimes it downloads additional data to support editing, but once it's done the image is guaranteed downloaded.

Comment: There is a cloud symbol next to photo file name in the photo Info (i in circle button). I can't find a list of what this indicates (mine are all a cloud with a tick). Guessing this may be the indicator.